# Can't copy/paste/cut Debian Jessie

Tags: vim, debian, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently installed Debian Jessie on my laptop and I can't figure out how to copy from, say, the web browser (I'm running Iceweasel) to the terminal window (notably, Vim, but also for the regular terminal). I've installed xclip because I've been reading online, and a bunch of posts have suggested it (it seems this problem comes up on other distros too), but I don't know if that's what I'm looking for. I've also tried creating a shortcut, but it hasn't worked so far.

Any suggestions? Or others who are having the same problem?

Also, I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I'm really stressing because I can't find any source where this problem had a reasonable solution.

Comment: Have you tried CTRL+SHIFT+C and CTRL+SHIFT+V for copy/paste in the terminal?

Comment: @MateuszPiotrowski Yes, neither of those shortcuts work.

Comment: Have you tried to copy by highlighting the text and then pasting it using the `Insert` button?

Answer (score 0):

In Debian the `CTRL+SHIFT+P` should work. If it's not, a workaround is to install Parcellite. Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install parcellite
```

To paste in terminal with Parcellite, you copy the text anywhere you want with `CTRL+C`, click in the Parcellite icon (a little clipboard icon, in Ubuntu it's on systray, in Debian I'm not sure), and you'll see the chunk of text you previously copied. Click on that text, go to terminal and press `CTRL+P`. It should paste the copied text. It's not cool, but solves your problem.

In Vim however, to copy/paste from outside Vim you need to include this line in you `.vimrc` file:

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus
```

To find your `.vimrc` file open Vim and type `:scriptname`. Vim will list all scripts open, the first one is your `vimrc` (and the path to it). Just open the file (you'll probably need root privilegies to write it), inserted the line above in the end and reload Vim. After that, you should use the `p` command in normal mode to paste things copied outside Vim.

Answer (score 0):

On some distros the default copy paste method is this...

Drag select the text with the mouse (or with shift + arrow keys) - this puts the text in the clipboard.  Then click the middle mouse button in the window you want to paste into.

Other alternatives for paste are shift+insert, right mouse click, or ctrl+v.

Note that some terminals use ctrl+letter to insert control codes, for instance ctrl+m is carriage return (char 13) and ctrl+j is linefeed.  So ctrl+v might be reserved and not used for pasting.